# Переключение по кнопкам. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Довольно тупой вопрос, но я никак не могу реализовать переключение по кнопке.

Алгоритм:
1 нажатие по кнопке: `Click_Main = true`

2 нажатие по кнопке: `Click_Main = false, Click2_Main = true`

И так по кругу.

Comment: `ClickMain = !ClickMain`

Answer (score 0):

вместо того что бы плодить кучу булевых переменных лучше ввести единственную переменную отвечающую за состояние.

Если состояния всего 2 - то это булевая переменная. Если больше - энам

```
private bool _state1Enabled = true;

//private State _appState = State.Hello;
//public enum State {
//    Hello,
//    World
//}

public void Button1_click(Object sender, events e){
    _state1Enabled != _state1Enabled;

    if (_state1Enabled) {
        Button1.Text = "Hello";
    } else {
        Button1.Text = "world";
    }
}
```